# unable to get error in sql syntax

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I have the coordinates of polygon in JSON object and I want to save them as polygon type in database. This is my code-

```
$query = "INSERT into table_name (Latitudes,Longitudes) VALUES(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('POLYGON('" . $Latitudes . "','" . $Longitudes . "')'))";
```

where `$Latitudes` and `$Longitudes` are the coordinates in JSON.

But the error is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near...at line 1

Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that the complete error message? "the right syntax to use near..." - right near what!?

Comment: Why are you trying to create and insert a ***single polygon*** from your latitude and longitude values, if the table has ***two fields; latitude and longitude***?

Comment: are you missing a " after ' of first )?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '\"[41.44272637767212,37.78808138412046,37.78808138412046,39.095962936305476]\"',' at line 1
This is the complete error message

Comment: I want to insert latitudes and longitudes in the fields as polygon type while currently they are in JSON.